# apk is not getting build and it's showing an TextCapitalization error

Tags: flutter, dart, apk

lib/methods/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/search_anchor.dart:1376:26: Error: The return type of the method '_SearchBarDefaultsM3.textCapitalization' is 'TextCapitalization/*1*/', which does not match the return type, 'TextCapitalization/*2*/?', of the overridden method, 'SearchBarThemeData.textCapitalization'.

i tried to build apk by just debuging the code in vs code.
but got an error stating "lib/methods/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/search_anchor.dart:1376:26: Error: The return type of the method '_SearchBarDefaultsM3.textCapitalization' is 'TextCapitalization/*1*/', which does not match the return type, 'TextCapitalization/*2*/?', of the overridden method, 'SearchBarThemeData.textCapitalization'."

Comment: Could you please provide the code you're using?

Comment: Can you provide the output for `flutter doctor`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.